# Stack div under an absolute div?

Tags: css, css-position

So I currently have the following HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }

    .table {
        display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
        max-width: 400px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
        max-width: 400px;
    } 

    .td1,
    .td2 {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 2px #aaaaaa solid;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #ffffff;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #333333;
    }

    .td2 {
        border-top: none;
        color: #777777;
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 400px;
        right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .under_div {
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="td1">Some random text that changes and can change the height of this div/td</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="td2">Some random text that changes and can change the height of this div/td</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="under_div">
            <p>Some random text that remains the same always
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My problem is that the second td (`td2`) needs to be `position: absolute`. There is a reason why it is so, so therefore it just can't be a regular div, as that would make this much easier :)

So, as you can see the next in the `under_div` is occupying the same space as the `td2`div. What I would like is for that to right under the `td2`div. In principle I could just try to position it so that it fits right under. But as stated in text of the divs the text changes, and therefore the height will be random for both the `td1` and `td2` divs.

So is there a way where I can stack the `under_div` div just under the `td2` div where it of course follows along according to whatever size the two other divs have, and not just stick around in one position ?

I have tried just making another table-div after the first one. But that doesn't seem to do anything either...

Comment: Why exactly do you need ``.td2`` to be ``position: absolute;``?

Comment: Because the div is supposed to be clickable via a script, which reveals another div beneath it. One fades away, the other fades in. If I don't use absolute position here, the divs are not stacked on top of each other, which means that when the fading occur one div is either above or under the other and then it looks like one div is hopping into place when the first div has faded away. So instead of this "hopping into place" behaviour, I just stacked them on top of each other with absolute position, which makes the transition smooth as intended.

Comment: Can you not make the second div have a fixed positioning and set the first div to have a higher z-index instead?

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/j00ykfa0/

Comment: 1) As stated, the div heights change depending on content, so I don't think fixed would do any good for that ?
2) There are more than one of these div-tables on my site, so one fixed position would not be enough.

Comment: Ah, maybe you have misunderstood me. There is ANOTHER div, similar to the td2 that is the one that it fades into. And beneath these two is where I would like the "Some random text" to be all the time. And it should be like that even though the fadeout td2 element has a larger height that the fadein td2 - and visa versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151177/discussion-between-mclemore-and-denver-dang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your design a little as I don't think it's possible to do this with an absolutely positioned element. You can accomplish what I believe you want using `float` and `clear`. An example jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n93t9fn5/1/).